# What is the best way to represent a single global class instance?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture

I have a project, which has its own filesystem. The class basically looks like this:

```
class ResourceManager {
public:
    std::string readFile(std::string const&);
private:
    std::vector<std::string> root;
};
```

This class is used everywhere in the project. So it's global and have a single instance. My current solution is that I create an instance in the main function and then pass it to all of my classes (they store a reference). I'm absolutely fine with this approach, besides that i need to pass the instance to regular functions, but I'm curious if it's possible to archive a better result.

A simple way of making a filesystem is just to have static functions, because you don't really need any variables to store. But in my case I have a variable called `root`, which stores search directories so that I can do something like this:

```
rm.addResourceRoot(ResourceType::images, "path/to/directory");
```

I can have a static variable `ResourceManager* instance` and method `ResourceManager& getRm() { return *instance; }` inside a class, but that approach feels kind of weird and probably isn't a "best practice". Probably outside-of-class functions like this will help to make it look better, but I'm still hesitating.

```
std::string readFile(std::string const& path) {
    return ResourceManager::getRm().readFile(path);
}
```

I can use singleton pattern, but everyone convinces me not to use it, because it's an anti-pattern and not good solution at all. This confuses me in some way so it would be great if anyone could explain the reasons to me.

In my opinion, the ideal access should look like this:

```
ResourceManager::readFile("path/to/file");
```

So what is the best way to represent such entities in a project?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with singletons. Like everything they have their place and they can be abused. If it fits your use case then go for it. That has to be better than maintaining a reference in every class in the system.

Comment: Problem with singleton is that instead been used in single place by `instance` and then passed by reference of pointer, they are accessed by `instance` function all over the code. After a while code is hard to test (hidden state which can't be reverted) and striping singleton (since understanding of requirements has changed) is almost impossible since it is everywhere.

Comment: @john The singleton pattern is worse than just having a global variable. At least a global variable looks global and has less typing.

Comment: Do you really want to use it *everywhere* in the project? Or just in the places that load resources? Will you ever want to load resources twice, from two different places? Like Minecraft's resource packs?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, _everywhere_ is not the right way to say that, but the point is that it can be used almost everywhere. To be more specific, I'm creating a game engine. And there are many use cases like "shaders", "textures", "scenes", "sounds" and much more. These are all different classes, so I should be ready to use it _everywhere_

Comment: @user253751 doesn't meter if it is used everywhere or in 30% of code. As long as use of function which instantiates singleton is used `O(N)` times to size of project soon or later it will bite you. If instantiation function is used `O(1)` times and instance is passed around you will be safe to modify code later.

Comment: @MarekR It's an argument against singletons because if you use it in only the loading code, you should pass it only to the loading code, so you can't accidentally use it outside of the loading code.